# Manipulating SPL

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I've performed an experiment on guitar tone - ive used a fourier analysis to find the different frequency components. The idea of this is to find the sound pressure level of the consonant intervals present in a guitar tone and compare it to the SPL of the dissonant intervals.

I have found the overall SPL of the consonant and dissonant intervals, but i'm stuck on comparing them. Would it make sense to divide two SPLs by each other? or how would i do that if not

for example, if i have 100.8 dB for all of the consonant intervals, can i just do 100.8/(overall SPL) to find the fraction of the overall SPL that is made up of "consonant" sound?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Frequency (intervals) and amplitude (SPL) are two completely independent parameters. Futhermore, an "interval" is simply the ratio of two frequencies -- it doesn't have an amplitude at all. Why do you think that they are somehow related?

Comment: @DaveTweed i have SPL for each frequency component found in the fourier analysis

Comment: So what is you "experiment" intended to accomplish?

Comment: @DaveTweed its a project, the idea is to be able to define how good or a bad a guitar's tone is by comparing how consonant/dissonant the output tone is

Comment: Well, good luck with that. You're going to have to make a lot of different measurements, and then determine experimentally which ones correlate with a subjective evaluation of "good" or "bad" tone. I'm not sure that this leaves us with an answerable question here. Are you asking how to measure the power of individual frequency components in a complex waveform, and how to combine those measurements into something that is subjectively meaningful?

Comment: @ Amy  Some 2nd harmonic energy, added to a sine wave, should add richness. So, yes, the ratio of SPL_2/SPL_1 gives information. Remember there is lots of mechanical motion occurring in the entire guitar, and the conversion of a "pluck" impulse into "richness"; that conversion occurs over some time (milliSeconds), thus explore 10milliSecond or 20milliSecond FFTs, along with windowing.

Comment: @DaveTweed dude i feel like youre being super unnecessarily condescending, chill out

Comment: @analogsystemsrf cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not in general make sense to divide SPL measurements into each other.

SPL is measured in dB, and decibels are already a logarithmic representation of power ratios. Therefore, if you have two SPL measurements and you want to find the ratio of their power, you simply subtract the measurements.